# Understand and Implement adjoint operator of gradient

Tags: calculus, derivatives, matlab, divergent-series

I have an equation as
[image]

With initial ui=vi; yi=0, tau=1;
[image]

I am implementing eq. 4.19 and 4.20 in MATLAB. Hence, I would like to ask you something.

1. The adjoint operator of gradient is similar the divergence operator, Is it right?

To explain what I can understand. I show it in my matlab code. Could you verify my code is correct or not?

Code:

```
%% Initial value
N=2; %i=1..2
%% Initial ui s.t ui>0 and \sum ui=1
u=rand(128,128,N);
a=sum(u,3);
for k = 1 : N
    u(:,:,k)=u(:,:,k)./a;
    v(:,:,k)=u(:,:,k);
end
tau=1;
theta=0.1;
y1 = zeros([size(u(:,:,1)) 2]);
y2 = zeros([size(u(:,:,1)) 2]);
for i=1:N_class
   [dxu dyu] = grad(u(:,:,i));
   %% Equation 4.19
   Nu1 = y1(:,:,i)+tau*dxu;
   Nu2 = y2(:,:,i)+tau*dyu;
   Nu  = sqrt(Nu1.^2+Nu2.^2);
   min_Nu=min(1/tau,Nu);
   y1(:,:,i) = min_Nu.*(y1(:,:,i) + tau*dxu)./Nu;
   y2(:,:,i) = min_Nu.*(y2(:,:,i) + tau*dyu)./Nu;
   %% Equation 4.20
   v(:,:,i)=u(:,:,i)-theta*div(y1(:,:,i),y2(:,:,i));
end
```

UPDATE div and grad function
This is my discrete gradient operator

This is my div and grad function  function

```
function [dxu dyu] = grad(u)
% [dxu dyu] = grad(u) computes the gradient of the function u
% with forward differences assuming
% Neumann boundary conditions    
[m n] = size(u);    
dxu = zeros(m,n);
dyu = zeros(m,n);
dxu(:,1:(n-1)) =  u(:,2:n) - u(:,1:(n-1));
dyu(1:(m-1),:) =  u(2:m,:) - u(1:(m-1),:);

function D = div(v1,v2)
% D = div(v1,v2) computes the divergence of the vector-
% field (v1, v2)^T with backward differences assuming
% Neumann boundary conditions
[m n] = size(v1);    
dxv1 = zeros(m,n);
dyv2 = zeros(m,n);    
dxv1(:,2:n) = v1(:,2:n) - v1(:,1:(n-1));    
dyv2(2:m,:) = v2(2:m,:) - v2(1:(m-1),:);
dxv1(:,1) = v1(:,1);% - 0
dyv2(1,:) = v2(1,:);% - 0    
%compute the divergence
D = dxv1 + dyv2;
```

Reference: Section 4.2-4.3 in the paper [FUZZY MUMFORD–SHAH MODEL](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/090753887)

Comment: The adjoint of grad is -div, but you have to be careful about boundary conditions. This follows from integration by parts (or summation by parts in the discrete case). It's enlightening to look at the matrix for the 1D discrete grad operator (forward difference operator). You can transpose the matrix directly.

Comment: Thank littleO. Based on your comment, the equation 4.20 can be implemented as v(:,:,i)=u(:,:,i)+theta*div(y1(:,:,i),y2(:,:,i)); Is it right?